# Resource of worked out examples of scattering amplitudes at one-loop for electroweak processes

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, education, scattering-cross-section, electroweak

Please suggest a book, notes, videos, etc where a few scattering amplitudes are worked out in (understandable) detail at **one-loop** in the standard electroweak theory. Feel free to recommend more than one resource. To be honest, I have calculated tree-level processes but never one-loop processes in the electroweak theory. So I needed some guidance. I would like to have to companion while I start to tackle a $W$-mediated or $Z$-mediated one-loop process in the electroweak theory. Ultimately, I am interested in finding how the amplitude/crosssection depends on the mass of the mediator, etc.

Comment: check my notes referred to in my profile.